Making a Python dictionary with a for loop for tokens and their model score
So I'm trying to make a Python dictionary consisting of a word and its model score for all of the words in my file. My issue is that I can't find a way to put the keyword for my iterator, words, into the score function without it literally giving me the score for the word "words". The score function gives you a probability score based on the word that is input, but I need it to cycle through each word in the file and give me the score for each.
Here is my code:
unigram_probs = [(dict.fromkeys(words, unigram_model.score("words"))) for words in dracula]

When I run my code, this is the output I'm getting:
{'project': 0.0006792647638196416,
 'gutenberg': 0.0006792647638196416,
 'ebook': 0.0006792647638196416,
 'dracula': 0.0006792647638196416}

Notice how in the above, every word is given the same probability score since it's pulling the score for the word "words" and applying it to all of them.
Instead, I need it to give me the probability score for each word that it loops through.
This is what Im expecting:
project 0.0012090748539600599
gutenberg 0.0004211384322782231
ebook 0.00017660643934248063
dracula 0.0005298193180274419


Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [mre]? I have some suspicions, but I can't confirm them unless I have a full, runnable example of your program.

unigram_model.score("words") passes the string 'words' to the function; do you mean unigram_model.score(words)? Also the code produces a List of  Dictionaries.

You can try iterating dracula for each word and find the score for each word and store in the unigram_probs dict in the same for loop.
unigram_probs = {}
for word in dracula:
  unigram_probs[word] = unigram_model.score(word)

Or a simpler way could be
unigram_probs = {word: unigram_model.score(word) for word in dracula}

